# Understanding an issue in a triple integral solution

Tags: integration

Here I have a triple integral

$$ \iiint f(x,y,z)dxdydz $$ on the region : $\{\sqrt[]{x^2+y^2} \le z \le \sqrt[]{4-x^2-y^2}\}  $

if we use cylindrical coordinates we have : **(1)** $  r\le z \le \sqrt[]{4-r^2} $

and when we want to do the integral :

we determine that : $  0 \le \theta \le 2\pi $ $ $   , $ $  $ 0 \le r \le \sqrt{2}$

my problem is the **z**

according the graph **z** is bigger than the Cone so it should be  : between $0 \le z \le \sqrt{4-r^2}$
**but** according to equation I determine that z is between : $r \le z \le \sqrt{4-r^2}$

what I'm missing here ?

Comment: my graph is z>0 half of a sphere and an upside down cone

Comment: It is $0 \le r \le z \le \sqrt{4-r^2}\le 2$

Comment: The cone opens up and the (hemi)sphere opens down, so the range for $z$ is above the cone ($z=r$) and below the sphere ($z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$).

Comment: But $r\le\sqrt{4-r^2}$ only if $r<\sqrt{2}$, so OP is correct.

Comment: @mike yes and we see that z is bigger that r

Comment: @Nameless according to the concern and the graph I can see that we should write z starting from $0$ but why can't we deduce this from the equations

Comment: If your limit of integration for $z$ goes from $0$ to $\sqrt{4 - r^2}$, you are not integrating over the cone then.

Comment: so **z** can start from r or from $0$ but the integration way changes ? (but leads to the same answer)

Comment: Maybe I am not fully understanding you, you say *according the graph z is bigger than the Cone so it should be : between* $0 \le z \le \sqrt{4-r^2}$ why? Why $z = 0$?

Comment: The shape is bounded above by the sphere and below by the cone.

Comment: @Nameless: I already paid attention to the triple integral. Thanks.

Comment: I'm asking without relationg to the function.  Why z starts from r and not from zero (according to the done equations)

Comment: @WasFr, then how did you get the same answer?

Comment: I did not I just asked if we get the same answer trying to find an answer to the discussed problem

Comment: @WasFr, if $f(x,y,z) = 0$ sure, but most cases no.

Comment: Ok , so from where should we start z from 0 ?(because of the graph) or from r (because of the written equations) and why ? Sorry I'm asking a lot

Comment: @WasFr  Please take a look at the figure I posted...

Comment: @mike thank you I'm looking at it right now

Comment: If you start from $z = 0$, you are integrating over the hemisphere ($z = 0$ is a plane).

Comment: yes now I got it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the cross section of the integration volume in $r-z$ plane:

[image: Here is the cross section in $r-z$ plane]

The integration of the volume $D$ is given by (assuming that $f(x,y,z)=F(z,r)$):
$$\int_D f(x,y,z)dxdydz=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} rdr \int_{r}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}dz F(z,r)$$

Comment: Thank you ! 
finally my problem is now almost cleared 
so to finish up can we do the integral in this order also ? :

$$\int_D f(x,y,z)dxdydz=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}dr \int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} dz \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta F(z,r)$$

Comment: sure. $\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=2\pi$